# jQuery Accordion not working to set height to content

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, accordion

I am trying to modify the accordion based on what I have researched in stackoverflow, and the height does still not change-- it is still the height of the tallest panel. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong or missing?
Here is what I entered in the HEAD--

```
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
  collapsible: true
});
</script>
<script>
$(".selector").accordion({ autoHeight: false }); 
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

You have three problems with your existing code. The following code should work for you:

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
});
```

1. You were not using the same selector for setting up your accordian.
2. You did not place your later code in a `.ready()` so it would not work properly if the accordian HTML was below the script tags.
3. The [jQuery accordian](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#no-auto-height) does not have a autoHeight option. Based on the documentation you should have been using heightStyle.

If these changes did not fix your problem, please provide your HTML as well.

Comment: Josh, gave a great response. I wanted to add that the default for Accordian is set to "auto" meaning all panels will be set to the height of the tallest panel.

Answer (score 3):

This work for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ heightStyle: "content", autoHeight: false, });
});
</script>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This solve my problem

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
       collapsible: true,
       autoHeight: false
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for,

```
heightStyle: "content"
```

As in,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ heightStyle: "content" });
 });
</script>
```

From the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#no-auto-height):

> Setting heightStyle: "content" allows the accordion panels to keep
>   their native height.

edit: I'm why people are suggesting autoHeight: false, because that's not even an option for .accordion. See the api for a full list of options here: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

@Nikos Gr's answer should be all you need, only should you choose to insert the script into an external file, make sure to link to the script in HTML AFTER you've linked to all the jquery UI files, like so:

first your jQuery files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../JQUERY/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="../JQUERY/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js">
</script>
<script src="../JQUERY/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

then your own js

```
<script src="animate.js"></script>
```

In that file, include the code as written by @Nikos GR, with the tips of @Josh Mein:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#accordion").accordion({
        heightStyle: "content"
    });

});
```

That should work just fine! If you want the script to be in your HTML do the same but without the "src" atrributes in the "`<script>`" element.